# Hiding the content before loading intro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to intro before loading the page content was hidden and shown after loading intro

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').removeClass('fullwidth');     
    $('#content').removeClass('fullwidth').delay(10).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('fullwidth');
        next();
    });
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/19r5L0x7/2/

Comment: What is .triggerFull in your fiddle?

Comment: `$.delay()` delays in ms, I don't think 10ms will be noticeable.

Comment: I did so
http://jsfiddle.net/19r5L0x7/3/

And fadding out too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this work around:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#content').removeClass('fullwidth');     
  //$('body').load(function() {
   $('#content').removeClass('fullwidth').delay(50).queue(function(next){
    $(this).addClass('fullwidth');
          next();
          
      });
    $(".fullwidth").width(100);
   
 var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
     var w = $(".fullwidth .expand").width() / $('.fullwidth .expand').parent().width() * 100;
if(w==100)
{
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    $(".load").fadeOut("slow");
    alert("done");
    //your show content code
}
 }, 0);
      return false;
  });
//});
```

```css
body {
 background: #161616 url(pattern_40.gif) top left repeat;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font: 12px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none;}

img {border: none;}

#content { 
 width:100%; 
 height:5px; 
 margin:50px auto; 
 background:#000;
}

.fullwidth .expand { 
 width:100%; 
 height:1px; 
 margin:2px 0; 
 background:#2187e7; 
 position:absolute;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.7);
    -moz-animation:fullexpand 10s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation:fullexpand 10s ease-out;
}

@-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
 0%  { width:0px;}
 100%{ width:100%;} 
}
@-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
 0%  { width:0px;}
 100%{ width:100%;} 
}

/* Loader Bar */

@-moz-keyframes fill {
 0%{ opacity:0; }
 100%{ opacity:1; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
 0%{ opacity:0; }
 100%{ opacity:1; } 
}

.trigger, .triggerFull, .triggerBar {
 background: #000000;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%, #000000 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%,#000000 100%);
 border-left:1px solid #111; border-top:1px solid #111; border-right:1px solid #333; border-bottom:1px solid #333; 
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 140px;
}
  
.trigger:hover, .triggerFull:hover, .triggerBar:hover {
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #202020 0%, #161616 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #202020 0%, #161616 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="load">
<div id="content">
<span class="expand"></span>
</div>
```